# Function declared as view error in solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract Wallet {

    uint balance = 0;
    
    bool a = true;
    
    
    function deposit(uint dep_amt) public {
        balance += dep_amt;
    }

    function withdraw (uint wdraw_amt) public view returns(string memory error){
        if(wdraw_amt<=balance){
         balance -= wdraw_amt;
        }
        
        else{
        error = "Insufficient Balance";
        return error;
        }

    }

    function getBalnce() public view returns (uint) {
       
        return balance;
    }
    

}
```

I'm very new to solidity and I'm trying to code a simple bank system which shows the balance and updates the balance according to the deposits and withdraws. I want to display an error in withdraw function when the amount to be withdrawn is greater than the balance but it shows an error saying:

```
TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.
```

Is there a way to possibly show the error from the same function?

If not, Please let me know an alternative.

Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `view` function promises not to modify the contract state - such as not to modify storage variables. See the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/contracts.html#view-functions) for more info.

But your code modifies the `balance` variable, which is a storage variable.

```
function withdraw (uint wdraw_amt) public view returns(string memory error){
    if(wdraw_amt<=balance){
     balance -= wdraw_amt;    // <-- here
    }
```

> *and updates the balance according to the deposits and withdraws*

Since one of your requirements is to actually update the storage variable, you need to remove the `view` modifier in order to be able to do that.

```
function withdraw (uint wdraw_amt) public returns(string memory error){
```

Users will then need to send a transaction (not a call) to execute the `withdraw()` function.

---

When you have a function executed by a transaction (and not by a call), you can get the string output in two ways.

1. Revert reason message

   ```
   function withdraw(uint wdraw_amt) public {
       if (wdraw_amt <= balance) {
           balance -= wdraw_amt;
       } else {
           revert("Insufficient Balance");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Event log

   ```
   event Error(string _message);

   function withdraw(uint wdraw_amt) public {
       if (wdraw_amt <= balance) {
           balance -= wdraw_amt;
       } else {
           emit Error("Insufficient Balance");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes I understand that I have to either remove the view modifier or the update of variable to overcome that error, but im asking if there is a way to display the error on running the function?? Im looking for the output to be in this way: [link](https://ibb.co/7JxZFqc)

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I updated my answer with ways to get the string from a transaction (that doesn't return values for transaction, unless it's an internal transation between contracts).

Comment: Thanks! The ways you mentioned work. I am using `require(wdraw_amt <= balance,"Insufficient funds, Try lesser amount!.");` which shows the error too, I thought to let you know. Thanks for the help brother!. Appreciate it!!